# CakePHP: _serialize not generating JSON response

Tags: php, json, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm using CakePHP v. 2.5.x...

I am trying to write a controller action that can respond with and HTML view OR JSON. For some reason, no matter what I try, the response is an HTML page, not markup.

This is in my `routes.php`:

```
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

This is my controller action:

```
public function login() {
    $this->set('foo', 'bar');
    $this->set('_serialize', array('foo') );
}
```

This returns the HTML for the `/users/login` view... NOT a JSON response.

It's very confusing because I have a different action which works fine with a .json extension. What am I missing?

**SOLVED!**

Thanks to ndm for pointing out that I forgot to include `RequestHandler` in my components.

Comment: And where do you include the request handler component? Also how are you invoking the action (URL wise)?

Comment: @ndm NOWHERE!!! Urggg... Thanks you so much! Please submit an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your app/Config/routes.php...

```
Router::parseExtensions();
```

One important thing to remember is that the piece of above code must be defined before this line

```
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

Then go to your controller & add `RequestHandler` component.

```
 public $components = array('RequestHandler');
```

Now your `/users/login` will be looks like

[image]
That's it.